# The content type “Document Collection Folder” at “…” is sealed

Tags: sharepoint-server, error, feature-activation, sharepoint-library

It is about 2 days when myself as full control and my users try to upload a document to SharePoint 2013 assets library this error popup for them

> The content type “Document Collection Folder” at “…” is sealed.

I searched and I activated the "Video and Rich Media" feature in site collection level but it didn't change.

It is very important and critical, so I appreciate if anyone can help regarding this issue.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating the asset library you're trying to upload content to?

Comment: Yes I activates the rich media feature and recreated the library but still I have error while try to add new film with New Document button. something strange that I recently notices is that I have "Add new Document " at top of my library but if it is assets library I should have "Add New Item"?!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reached the answer my self and after activating "Rich Video" and "Doc Set " feature and recreating the Library it got solve.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I confirm you must:

1. Delete the library "Asset Library".
2. Activate the 2 Site Collection features: Document Sets, Video and Rich Media.
3. Create a new "Asset Library".
4. Re-upload files.